# Webpacker can't find entry.js in manifest.json

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, webpack

I am running this code in the development environment but I always get this error code and do not find any solution: I deleted the node-module and reinstalled it. I checked everything but nothing seems to work. All the answers are just for the production environment, but mine doesnt work in the development environment. Does anyone know why?

```
1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
   unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
Your manifest contains:
{
}:
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9
```

my entry file is here:
[image]

this is my application.html.erb file:

````
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ProductHuntApp</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'entry' %> 

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <%= favicon_link_tag "https://res.cloudinary.com/dekgrddbo/image/upload/v1506108218/product-hunt-logo-orange-960_fvifwi.png" %>

  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>```

and here is my webpacker.yml file:
````

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  additional_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    # Hot Module Replacement updates modules while the application is running without a full reload
    hmr: false
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR; it inserts a script to take care of live reloading
    inline: true
    # Should we show a full-screen overlay in the browser when there are compiler errors or warnings?
    overlay: true
    # Should we use gzip compression?
    compress: true
    # Note that apps that do not check the host are vulnerable to DNS rebinding attacks
    disable_host_check: true
    # This option lets the browser open with your local IP
    use_local_ip: false
    # When enabled, nothing except the initial startup information will be written to the console.
    # This also means that errors or warnings from webpack are not visible.
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

Comment: I see ` application.html.erb` call `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` if you using webpack change it to `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>`
And `entry.jsx` is reactjs file this is document refer [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails), hope it help you